# I need the default set of software sources to recover my installation

Tags: 11.04, kubuntu, software-sources

I just had the default ones. They are ALL gone. I can't install any software at all. I am using Kubuntu 11.04 x86.

I have no idea why they disappeared. They just did. :/

How do I get the default software sources back?

(I know the sudo add-apt-repository command, but I need to names of the default repositories)

Answer (score 2):

here is a copy of mine

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 11.04 _Natty Narwhal_ - Release i386 (20110423)]/ natty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main
```

Comment: Could you please alter oneiric to natty yourself? You need to do this once. If only 2 people copy this it is 1 more person that needs to edit this (with all kinds of chances of someone making a typo).

Comment: I replaced Terry's oneiric sources.list with my natty one. It includes Universe and Restricted, etc.

Comment: @Rinzwind, as requested amended to natty. @djeikyb mine does include universe and restricted etc